# How to reformat XML layouts in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

In my project I created some UI in the **design tab** of an XML layout. But when I go to the Text tab, the code is not properly formatted!

I selected **Reformat code** from **right click menu** on `XML` but the code is still not properly formatted!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:hint="Name"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I **reformat** my above code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML layout doesn't line break in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587501/xml-layout-doesnt-line-break-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **Reformat Code** works properly In Android Studio

Your XML File Code after use **Reformat Code**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It works with **CTRL + ALT + L**

Or you can just Click On **Code** in Menu Bar and Select **Code Format** as shown in Image

[image]

Comment: thanks dear, but in my above question i say it. i use shortcuts and menu items. but not reformat again!

Comment: now you can copy that code i have reformat for you and I think there is issue in your android studio try to change tags or repost in Android-Studio Tag. Thank you

Comment: @Jakewarton please try with CTRL + ALT + Shift + L

Comment: not work me again this shourtcut! my android studio version is 3.2.1

Comment: @Jakewarton then try to post same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio

Comment: I thought the "Jake Wharton" says dear. well played.

Comment: option + command + L works on my MacOS, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[Android Studio XML Code Scheme - like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Kdn.png)

Change XML Code Scheme for "Default IDE" in Android Studio Preferences.

Hope it works for you.