# XML layout doesn't line break in android studio

Tags: android-studio

After I updated my android studio , the XML formatting is ruined in the layout editor. Initially each attribute was on a separate line. Now however two or three attributes take a line .

[image]

I went into Settings->Editor->CodeStyle->XML and under the Layout Files region I have Wrap Attributes set as Wrap Always and Insert Line Break After First attribute is checked.

Yet the effect doesn't appear .

Any pointers?

[image: Settings Screen]

Comment: try cltrl+alt+L

Comment: still same...i have two attributes per line still

Comment: Can you share your settings as ScreenShot?

Comment: I suggest to check "Insert line break after last attribute". There are 2 such check boxes which are unchecked on your last screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had occurred. Coz u r using **Project Scheme** . To fix this go `Preferences>>Code Style>>XML` on Scheme Combo Box , change to **Default IDE**

For Me, I overwrite project to **Project Scheme**( one that u don't like) with Default IDE. select setting icon  and Copy to Project.

[image]

After all finished, Close preference pane with **OK** ,And then u are good to go.
Good Luck!

Comment: I did as you suggested. Unfortunately my xml's still have two attributes per line

Comment: be sure make Restore Default. before u do my steps. I thinks, default config is overwritten

Comment: let me give it a try in ten minutes

Answer (score 1):

Just go to **File->Settings->Keymap** and search **Reformat Code**. You can find your shortcut to format your code and also you can remove and add new shortcuts for this.

[image: Reformat Code]